# Function pointer problem

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I am trying to use a function pointer, but the 3 lines below just do not seem to want to cooperate...

I'm getting error code C3867.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

In .h file

```
void MyFunc(int, FILEINFO*(*)(FILEINFO*), FILEINFO*, int);
```

The definition in the .cpp file

```
void MyFunc(int number, FILEINFO*(*GetFiles)(FILEINFO*), FILEINFO* args, int type);
```

Then here is where I'm actually calling the function

```
MyFuncClass->MyFunc(GetNumber(), &BigClass::PassThis, GetArgs(), TheType);
```

Any problems jump out?

Comment: BigClass::PassThis is a static function, right?

Comment: First result when googling your error code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0x1aatf(VS.80).aspx

Seems very clear xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass a non-static member function of a class as an
ordinary function pointer, since a member function implicitly uses the
this-pointer. A solution for this is to define a static member function that takes a pointer
to the class as it's first argument and wraps the call to `BigClass::PassThis` and pass a pointer to that member function instead. Please see 
[The Function Pointer Tutorials](http://www.newty.de/fpt/callback.html#member) for more information.

A better solution might be to look into using functors instead.

Comment: Also take a look into boost::function, boost::bind for other solutions to the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

What is the definition of `BigClass::PassThis()`?  Is it a static class member function or a regular member function?  If it's a regular member function, you can't do that, because it has a hidden `this` parameter.  See [question 33.4](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.4) of the C++ FAQ Lite.

Answer (score 2):

We'd need to see the definition of BigClass. Unless PassThis is a static member function, what you've done can't work because regular member functions can't be passed as a function pointer the way you are doing it (among other things, you've got no 'this' parameter).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that `&BigClass::PassThis` is a pointer to a member function and not a pointer to an ordinary function.

Comment: It's worth noting for those following along at home that it's not so important what type is `BigClass::PassThis` so long as the result of applying the `&` operator to it gets you a pointer to the appropriately typed function.